# On entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Do there exist entire functions that aren't constant but are bounded on every vertical strip??

My guess is there do exist such functions, but I am unable to cook up any examples. When I was digging for answers, I came across a post which deals with entire functions bounded on every line (horizontal or vertical), but that wasn't of much help.

Comment: What about the exponential?

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked the almost obvious! That works. Thanks.